# Cannot order drop down list value alphabetically using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The drop down list can not ordered alphabetically using Angular.js. Here is my code:

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Business Name :</span>
<select class="form-control"  id="restau" ng-model="restaurant" ng-options="qua.name for qua in listOfRestaurant | orderBy:'name' track by qua.value" ng-change="getDayFromSpecial('restau');">
 </select>
</div> 

$scope.listOfRestaurant=[{
        name:'Select Business Name',
        value:''
}]
$scope.restaurant=$scope.listOfRestaurant[0];

$http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"php/customerInfo.php?action=restaurant",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj){
            var data={'name':obj.rest_name,'value':obj.member_id};
            $scope.listOfRestaurant.push(data);
        })
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    })
```

Here my problem is I can order the list but `Select Business Name` is coming in middle in this list which should come only first and selected.

Comment: post the json you load

Comment: @Sajeetharan : All json value coming from database.I am updating my post again.

Comment: I presume you're appending the select with your `$scope.listOfRestaurant` array? If so, add the `Select Business Name` option first then append the rest

Comment: can u plz post a plunkr or somethng.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney : I am adding `Select Business Name` for 0th index. Check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write like this.

```
<select name="quarter" ng-model="Quarter" 
        ng-options="obj.value as obj for obj in options | orderBy:'toString()'">
        <option value="" >Select Business Name</option>
</select>
```

don't put your select business name in data list.

Comment: but i can not get this value `$scope.Quarter.value`.its throwing error.

Comment: hi satya, i ve created fiddle for u just check, hope this will help you . http://jsfiddle.net/upj8n47m/1/

Answer (score 0):

By using `orderBy:'toString()'` with ng-repeat you can sort list value `alphabetically` using angular.js

Example :

```
<select name="quarter" ng-model="Quarter" 
        ng-options="obj.value as obj for obj in options | orderBy:'toString()'">

</select>
```

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upj8n47m/)

Comment: @ p2 : i can oreder properly but 0th index text is coming 2 times. Please check my post again.

Comment: @satya: if you can show some sample of `response` that would really help me